# How do I parallelize the next code in C so it iterates through all rows and columns? (linear regression program)

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads, regression

I'm doing a parallelization assignment in C from a linear regression calculation program but I am just supposed to parallelize the part that calculates all additions just right before the linearity calculation.

Original code. Arguments: number of elements

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N 50000

int nn;
int *X[N+1],*apX, *Y;
long long *sumaX, *sumaX2, sumaY, *sumaXY; 
double *A, *B;

int main(int np, char*p[])
{
    int i,j;
    double sA,sB;
    clock_t ta,t;

    assert(np==2);

    nn = atoi(p[1]);
    assert(nn<=N);
    srand(1);

    printf("Dimensio dades =~ %g Mbytes\n",((double)(nn*(nn+11))*4)/(1024*1024)); 

    apX = calloc(nn*nn,sizeof(int)); assert (apX);
    Y = calloc(nn,sizeof(int)); assert (Y);
    sumaX = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaX);
    sumaX2 = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaX2);
    sumaXY = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaXY);
    A = calloc(nn,sizeof(double)); assert (A);
    B = calloc(nn,sizeof(double)); assert (B);

    // Initialization
    X[0] = apX;
    /*for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<nn;j+=8)            
            X[i][j]=rand()%100+1;
        Y[i]=rand()%100 - 49;
    X[i+1] = X[i] + nn;
    }*/
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<nn;j+=8)            
            X[i][j]=90;
        Y[i]=40;
    X[i+1] = X[i] + nn;
    }

    // add (parallelization part)
    sumaY = 0;
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
    sumaX[i] = sumaX2[i] = sumaXY[i] = 0;
        for (j=0;j<nn;j++) {
        sumaX[i] += X[i][j];
        sumaX2[i] += X[i][j] * X[i][j];
        sumaXY[i] += X[i][j] * Y[j];
    }
    sumaY += Y[i];
    }

    // linearity calculation
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
    B[i] = sumaXY[i] - (sumaX[i] * sumaY)/nn;
    B[i] = B[i] / (sumaX2[i] - (sumaX[i] * sumaX[i])/nn);
    A[i] = (sumaY -B[i]*sumaX[i])/nn;
    }

    // check
    sA = sB = 0;
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
            //printf("%lg, %lg\n",A[i],B[i]);
        sA += A[i];
        sB += B[i];
    }

    printf("Suma elements de A: %lg B:%lg\n",sA,sB);

exit(0);
}
```

Parallelization. Arguments: number of elements and threads

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 50000
#define MAX_THREADS 256

int nn, numThreads;
int *X[N+1],*apX, *Y;
long *sumaX, *sumaX2, sumaY, *sumaXY;
double *A, *B;
int range[MAX_THREADS];
pthread_mutex_t mutex= PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int ret;

void * parallel_code(void * id){
    int index = (intptr_t) id;
    int i, ini, row, col;
    int rowAux = -5;

    if(index == 0)
        ini = 0;
    else
        ini = range[index-1];

    for(i=ini; i<range[index]; i++){
        row = i/nn;
        col = i%nn;

        sumaX[row] += X[row][col];
        sumaX2[row] += X[row][col] * X[row][col];
        sumaXY[row] += X[row][col] * Y[col];

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if(rowAux != row){
            sumaY += Y[row];
            rowAux = row;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }else{
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int np, char*p[])
{
    int i,j,index;
    double sA,sB;
    clock_t ta,t;
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];

    assert(np==3);

    nn = atoi(p[1]);
    assert(nn<=N);
    srand(1);

    numThreads = atoi(p[2]);
    assert(numThreads >= 2 && numThreads <= MAX_THREADS);

    printf("Dimensio dades =~ %g Mbytes\n",((double)(nn*(nn+11))*4)/(1024*1024)); 

    memset(range,0,numThreads*sizeof(int));

    apX = calloc(nn*nn,sizeof(int)); assert (apX);
    Y = calloc(nn,sizeof(int)); assert (Y);
    sumaX = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaX);
    sumaX2 = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaX2);
    sumaXY = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaXY);
    A = calloc(nn,sizeof(double)); assert (A);
    B = calloc(nn,sizeof(double)); assert (B);

    // Inicialitzacio
    /*X[0] = apX;
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<nn;j+=8)            
            X[i][j]=rand()%100+1;
        Y[i]=rand()%100 - 49;
    X[i+1] = X[i] + nn;
    }*/
    X[0] = apX;
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<nn;j+=8)            
            X[i][j]=90;
        Y[i]=40;
    X[i+1] = X[i] + nn;
    }

    int portion = nn*nn/numThreads;
    int mod = nn*nn % numThreads;

    if(mod != 0.00){
        mod = mod*numThreads;
        for(i=0; i<mod; i++){
            range[i] = range[i] + 1;
        }
    }

    range[0] = range[0] + portion;
    for(i=1; i<numThreads; i++){
        range[i] += range[i-1] + portion;
    }

    sumaY = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    for (index = 0; index < numThreads; index++)
    {
        assert(!pthread_create(&threads[index], NULL, parallel_code, (void *) (intptr_t)index));
    }

    for(index = 0; index < numThreads; index++)
    {
        assert(!pthread_join(threads[index], NULL ));
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
    B[i] = sumaXY[i] - (sumaX[i] * sumaY)/nn;
    B[i] = B[i] / (sumaX2[i] - (sumaX[i] * sumaX[i])/nn);
    A[i] = (sumaY -B[i]*sumaX[i])/nn;
    }

    // check
    sA = 0;
    sB = 0;
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
            //printf("%f, %f\n",sA,sB);
        sA += A[i];
        sB += B[i];
    }
    printf("Suma elements de A: %lg B:%lg\n",sA,sB);

exit(0);
}
```

So far I've done some parallelization as you can see in the code above: calculated how much data every thread has to work with (that's what the variables "portion" and "mod" are for), created threads for every portion, created a mutex to control SumaY access... The thing is the current program just works with small values (like 2000 as number of elements for example) and don't really know why. Might be because the thread doesn't read all necessary columns and/or rows as every time the program displays a wrong value this value is always lower than the right one, so might indicate the program is missing some data to read. To be fair I think I'm pretty close to the right solution so I came here as a last resource. Also, take into account splitting the task into multiple portions for every thread is a must for the assignment.

Thanks a lot in advance.

27/01/2021 EDIT (working code, fast and slow versions):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 50000
#define MAX_THREADS 256

int nn, numThreads;
int *X[N+1],*apX, *Y;
long long *sumaX, *sumaX2, sumaY, *sumaXY;
double *A, *B;
int range[MAX_THREADS];
pthread_mutex_t mutex= PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
// Slow version
//int visitedRows[N];

void * parallel_code(void * args){
    int index = (*(int*)args);
    int i, j, ini;
    // Slow version
    // int row, col;

    if(index == 0)
        ini = 0;
    else
        ini = range[index-1];
    
    for(i=ini; i<range[index]; i++){
        // Fast version
        for (j=0;j<nn;j++) {
            sumaX[i] += X[i][j];
            sumaX2[i] += X[i][j] * X[i][j];
            sumaXY[i] += X[i][j] * Y[j];
        }
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        sumaY += Y[i];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        // Slow version
        /*row = i/nn;
        col = i%nn;
        sumaX[row] += X[row][col];
        sumaX2[row] += X[row][col] * X[row][col];
        sumaXY[row] += X[row][col] * Y[col];
        
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if(visitedRows[row] == 0){
            visitedRows[row] = 1;
            sumaY += Y[row];
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }else{
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }*/
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int np, char*p[])
{
    int i,j,index;
    double sA,sB;
    unsigned int thread_args[MAX_THREADS];
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREADS];

    assert(np==3);

    nn = atoi(p[1]);
    assert(nn<=N);
    srand(1);

    numThreads = atoi(p[2]);
    assert(numThreads >= 2 && numThreads <= MAX_THREADS);

    printf("Dimensio dades =~ %g Mbytes\n",((double)(nn*(nn+11))*4)/(1024*1024)); 

    memset(range,0,numThreads*sizeof(int));
    // Slow version
    //memset(visitedRows,0,nn*sizeof(int));

    apX = calloc(nn*nn,sizeof(int)); assert (apX);
    Y = calloc(nn,sizeof(int)); assert (Y);
    sumaX = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaX);
    sumaX2 = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaX2);
    sumaXY = calloc(nn,sizeof(long long)); assert (sumaXY);
    A = calloc(nn,sizeof(double)); assert (A);
    B = calloc(nn,sizeof(double)); assert (B);
    // Inicialitzacio
    X[0] = apX;
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<nn;j+=8)            
            X[i][j]=rand()%100+1;
        Y[i]=rand()%100 - 49;
    X[i+1] = X[i] + nn;
    }

    // Fast version
    int portion = nn/numThreads;
    int mod = nn % numThreads;

    // Slow version
    //int portion = nn*nn/numThreads;
    //int mod = nn*nn % numThreads;
    
    for(i=0; i<numThreads; i++){
        range[i] = portion;
        if (i != 0) range[i] += range[i-1];
        if (i < mod) range[i]++;
    }
    
    sumaY = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    for (index = 0; index < numThreads; index++)
    {
        thread_args[index] = index;
        assert(!pthread_create(&threads[index], NULL, parallel_code, &thread_args[index]));
    }

    for(index = 0; index < numThreads; index++)
    {
        assert(!pthread_join(threads[index], NULL ));
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
    B[i] = sumaXY[i] - (sumaX[i] * sumaY)/nn;
    B[i] = B[i] / (sumaX2[i] - (sumaX[i] * sumaX[i])/nn);
    A[i] = (sumaY -B[i]*sumaX[i])/nn;
    }

    // check
    sA = sB = 0;
    for (i=0;i<nn;i++) {
            //printf("%f, %f\n",sA,sB);
        sA += A[i];
        sB += B[i];
    }
    printf("Suma elements de A: %lg B:%lg\n",sA,sB);

exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It's not related to the problem you describe, but both versions of the program abuse `assert` badly.  The `assert` macro is for checking that *your code* is correct, not for checking that input or runtime results are correct.  If an assertion ever fails then by definition that means the program is buggy.  Moreover, depending on how the program is compiled, the asserted conditions might never be tested at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger did not know abusing assert is bad to be honest, thank you. Most of these are from the teacher's original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mutex initialization and destruction

You having initialized `mutex` via the static initializer, it is erroneous to initialize it again via `pthread_mutex_init()` (unless you first tear it down with `pthread_mutex_destroy()`).

Additionally, it is unnecessary, albeit not wrong, to tear down the mutex after joining all the threads.

#### Work distribution, part 1

This is wrong:

> ```
>     int mod = nn*nn % numThreads;
>
>     if(mod != 0.00){
>         mod = mod*numThreads;
>         for(i=0; i<mod; i++){
>             range[i] = range[i] + 1;
>         }
>     }
> ```

I think you are trying to distribute the excess of the `nn * nn` data among the threads, but there are only `mod` excess elements, not `mod * NumThreads` of them.  I think you meant

```
    int mod = nn*nn % numThreads;

    // No need to pre-test whether mod is nonzero.
    // mod is used as originally computed, not multiplied by numThreads.
    for (i = 0; i < mod; i++) {
        range[i] = range[i] + 1;
    }
```

The original version not only sets the ranges incorrectly, but it also overruns the bounds of array `range` when `nn*nn % numThreads` is greater than 1.

**But probably this is all moot. See below.**

#### Work distribution, part 2

I suspect that the main problem is that these lines ...

> ```
>         sumaX[row] += X[row][col];
>         sumaX2[row] += X[row][col] * X[row][col];
>         sumaXY[row] += X[row][col] * Y[col];
> ```

... are executed by the thread function without locking the mutex. `sumX`, `sumX2`, and `sumXY` point to data shared among the threads, and as the work has been split among them, it is entirely possible for more than one thread to contribute to the same elements.  In that event, you have data races, and the resulting behavior is undefined.

Naively, you could solve that problem by moving those computations inside the critical section, after the `pthread_mutex_lock()`, since right now you do lock and unlock the mutex on every iteration of the loop.  But there are several problems with that, especially:

- you would squeeze out most of the already constrained opportunity for thread concurrency; and
- mutex operations are comparatively expensive, and with otherwise only a handful of arithmetic operations per loop iteration, locking and unlocking the mutex as frequently as you are doing is likely to dominate the performance.

I would be surprised if the parallel version weren't slower than the serial version if you approached it that way.

What you should do instead is limit the number of threads actually used to at most the number of rows of data, and assign data to threads on a whole-row basis.  No row should be split across two or more threads.  That will eliminate the aforementioned data races without defeating the purpose of parallelizing.

I would also modify the thread function so that it locks the mutex only when it adds per-row results to the global sum.  That will get you a lot more concurrency than you have now.

This will give you a less even division of data among threads, and perhaps fewer threads overall, but it doesn't help you anyway to have more threads than you have execution units to run them on.  When the number of rows is large relative to the number of threads, the effect of the unevenness will not be very pronounced, whereas in small cases, the overall runtime isn't so much of an issue in the first place.  More importantly, the computations should produce correct results, and the reduction in locking should substantially improve performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborated answer, I am accepting it. I fixed the code on my own though (it works but not too sure if it is optimized enough) and got a faster version by using nn instead of nn*nn. I am editing the original post with the working code, both fast and slow versions.